# Error 33: Too many arguments to 'Public ReadOnly Default Property Item(index As Integer) As SuppliersDataSet.SuppliersRow'

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm a complete newbie to programming languages, especially VB.net.

I keep getting the following error message and not sure how to resolve it after several hours trying;

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: BC30057: Too many arguments to 'Public ReadOnly Default Property Item(index As Integer) As SuppliersDataSet.SuppliersRow'.

Source Error:

    Line 11: 
    Line 12:         supplierConfirm =
    Line 13:         confirmSupplier.GetDataByConfirmSupplier(Me.CompanyNameTextBox.Text, Me.AccountManagerTextBox.Text, Me.AddressTextBox.Text, Me.CityTextBox.Text, Me.RegionTextBox.Text, Me.PostCodeTextBox.Text, Me.CountryTextBox.Text, Me.PhoneTextBox.Text, Me.FaxTextBox.Text, Me.EmailTextBox.Text, Me.WebsiteTextBox.Text, Me.FacebookTextBox.Text, Me.TwitterTextBox.Text)
    Line 14: 
    Line 15:         Dim id As Integer = supplierConfirm.Rows(0)("SupplierID")
```

Comment: You have two arguments on line 15. Is `supplierConfirm.Rows` a dictionary or array?

Comment: This is not a c# question.  You need to remove the C# tag.

Comment: The cause of the problem is on line 13 where you created the Enumerable.

Comment: could you expand slightly on this for me please @tdbeckett - thanks for the correction of the post btw!

Comment: I'm going to say derp.  the problem is line 15.  You are accessing the dataset incorrectly.  VB does things weird.   Here's some info on how to work with datasets.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bw9ksd6.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-5

Comment: It should look something like this: Dim customerIDValue As String =
    CType(dataset1.Tables("Customers").Rows(0).Item("CustomerID"), String)  granted this example is for a string, but you should be able to figure it out with this.

Comment: Also a simple google search would have given you this link.